# Powering the Pi 4 - safe voltage levels and current requirements

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-4

How to safely power the Pi 4, more specifically:

1. What voltage levels are safe to power the Pi 4 via the USB-C connector or via the GPIO header?
2. What are the current requirements?
3. What Power Management ICs / voltage regulators are used by the Pi 4? The [official schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_4b_4p0_reduced.pdf) seem to lack a description of U2 and U3.

Answer (score 17):

1. Voltage level

The power management IC (PMIC, see section 3) is a MXL7704 with an input voltage range of 4.0 V to 5.5 V and an *absolute maximum* rating of 6 V that must not be exceeded.

Considering that the downstream USB ports are directly connected to the 5 V power rail the 5 V supply should also comply with USB [electrical specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB): 4.45 V to 5.25 V (USB 3.0)

(*TBC*): Furthermore the "Power good" pins of the PMIC used on the Pi 3B+ (and thus likely on the Pi 4 too) was used to trigger the low voltage warning at 4.63±0.07 V ([Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51616/19949)).

The reasonable voltage range to power the Pi therefore is: **4.7 V to 5.25 V**

---

2. Current requirement

[Raspberry Pi 4 spec](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/) recommends a **3 A supply (15 W)**, with a minimum current of 2.5 A if downstream USB peripherals consume less than 500 mA in total.

---

3. PMIC

The Foundations [blog](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-4-on-sale-now-from-35/) shows this [picture](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2019/06/POWER_CU.jpg) of the power management section on the PCB. The PMIC is a [MXL7704](https://www.maxlinear.com/ds/mxl7704.pdf) - the same IC is used on the Pi 3B+.

[image]

Comment: FYI: The original Pi 4 has a non-compliant USB-C power port implementation. Smart power adapters which use "e-marked" cables with chips to negotiate power may not work. [Ars Technica: "Raspberry Pi admits to faulty USB-C design on the Pi 4"](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/07/raspberry-pi-4-uses-incorrect-usb-c-design-wont-work-with-some-chargers/)

Comment: @l--marcl yes, thanks. There are some other questions around here about the USB-C port, feel free to post an answer about this issue there if it is not already addressed.

Comment: Pi 4 Revision 1.2 fixed the USB-C non-spec power problem. Released around Feb 2020. See ["How to Check if Your Raspberry Pi 4 Model B is Rev1.2?" on tutorial.cytron.io](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2020/02/22/how-to-check-if-your-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-is-rev1-2/)