# raspberry pi prevent overload current from turning on a high current motor

Tags: power-supply, electronics, voltage, dc-motor, current

I am trying to use only 1 power supply instead of 2 to power Raspberry Pi and motor, but when I turn on the high current (>10A) motor, it will lead to the Raspberry Pi restarting. I guess it is something about the current overload protection? Below are the wiring I have done.

1st wiring using two 12V power supply. Everything works perfect.

[image]

2nd wiring using only 1 12V power supply. The Pi would restart once I turn on the motor.

[image]

Any suggestions? Any module I can buy or any rewiring I can do to prevent this case? Thanks.

Comment: Add a large capacitor and a diode just upstream of the 12 to 5V Converter.  Diode is to ensure current only flows from supply to cap.  cap is to hold charge for the moment supply gets hit by motor.  Of course it wont work if steady state of power supply output while running motor +a few amps is less than 5V + diode drop.

Comment: @Abel any model of diode you would suggest? Thanks

Comment: what's the model of 12V to 5V? I'd get a rectifier diode that covers ~2X the max 12V amperage that thing could draw... but pi probably doesn't need that.  Just pulling from what ai have now, I'd use SR560.

Comment: @Abel I’m using XY-3606

Comment: Use a Schottky diode - one with a low forward voltage drop (see answer below).

Comment: Simple - whatever power supply you are using is inadequate. This is not a Pi problem.

Comment: @Seamus a voltage drop upstream of the 12-5V shouldn't be a big deal.  you're dropping it to 5V later anyway.

Comment: @Seamue and Abel Thanks for all the effort and long answer. I need some times to digest and do some little testing and searches. Will come back later.

Comment: @Abel: The diode and cap should be on the RPi-side of the 12-to-5 regulator. Putting it on the 12V side is not the way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for suggestions. Perhaps it would be better if you first understood the *source* of the issue you've described?

#### Answer:

Your issue is caused by inadequate [load regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_regulation) in your power supply. [Here's a short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsZHx5v5sYI) that explains what's happening, and shows one way to test a power supply's load regulation performance.

Your issue is exacerbated by two other factors:

1. RPi's tight input voltage tolerances, and
2. Inrush currents to your DC motors

You need more information to move toward a resolution in an *objective* fashion, but unless you have some decent test equipment, you'll have to sort this out through a *trial-and-error* process. The good news is that you'll learn some things!

The simplest approach is to stick with the *two-supply-solution* shown in your question. However, the [`VNH2SP30` drivers](https://www.st.com/en/automotive-analog-and-power/vnh2sp30-e.html) have the capability to reduce the inrush current drawn by the motors; managing the inrush current ***may*** be enough to get you to a workable solution.

You should also understand that these power-induced restarts may corrupt your filesystem. Therefore, it's especially important that you maintain a [reliable backup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/120154/83790).

That concludes my answer - following are some more detailed comments and suggestions that may or may not be useful:

#### Other Comments & Suggestions:

1. ***Comment:*** Your power supply ([XY-3606](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VT1S85X)) apparently has no published specifications. This is unfortunately typical of the **electronic junk** that is sold in our mainstream retail outlets today. As long as we continue buying this **junk**, vendors and manufacturers will continue to sell it.
2. ***Suggestion:*** Low cost power supplies for *hobbyists* are available from [more responsive (and responsible) sources](https://www.pololu.com/category/136/voltage-regulators). Ask questions before you buy, and insist on documentation and product specifications. Don't buy [a pig in a poke](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+pig+in+a+poke).
3. ***Comment:*** Raspberry Pis have fairly stringent tolerances for input voltage. The ["official documentation"](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply) is fairly [*sketchy*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sketchy) on this point, but lists 4.63V as the "warning level". A more informative discussion of input voltage requirements is in the [RPi SE Q&A, "Powering the Pi 4"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99962/83790). Much has been written on this subject, most [all available for the cost of an Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+input+voltage+requirement&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web).
4. ***Comment:*** Your project may exacerbate the RPi's tight input voltage requirements. This, due to the fact that [dc motors draw transient inrush currents](https://www.jadelearning.com/blog/understanding-motor-starting-inrush-currents-nec-article-430-52/) that may be several times the value of their rated steady-state current. In other words, the motor's inrush current may be so large as to exceed your power supply's load regulation specs (which aren't published, so yeah - double trouble).
5. ***Suggestion:*** Hopefully you can now see that you are dealing with several unknowns - any one of which could account for the RPi shutdown behavior you've seen. An oscilloscope would allow you to see the depth, and the timing, of the voltage transient on the output of your power supply. This would inform you as to the energy storage required, and whether a diode-isolated holdup capacitor might be useful.

   We can tell you that the [energy storage available from a capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) is straightforward to calculate (**W = (1/2) * C * V<sup>2</sup>**), but a measurement (or some trial-and-error) are required for an accurate estimate of ***how much*** energy is needed. For example, a voltage transient that dips to 1 volt for 20 msec requires far more energy (and a larger capacitor) than a transient that dips to only 4 volts for 2 msec.

   The diode is important also as it consumes power (due to its voltage drop) as it conducts current from the supply. In general, Schottky diodes are best for these applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was waiting for my pi replacement, so it takes a little long. I finally checked I need to use around 700mA current, so I picked a SR140 diode, which is good for 1A and 40V. Thanks again