# Pi cannot boot when encrypted USB SSD drive is attached

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspbian-buster, security, encryption

I have a Pi 4, running Raspbian 10 Buster. I have an attached SSD drive with LUKS encryption. When I restart the Pi, it wouldn't boot if the SSD is attached. Once I unplug it, it boots well and I can connect the USB drive and works well after entering the password. I must've did something wrong..Please help!

Comment: Add `program_usb_boot_timeout=1` to `/boot/config.txt`. Would works.

Comment: I tried. Didn't work.

Comment: How the RPi boot? Any log? Any error?

Comment: *the USB drive and works well after entering the password* - so you need to enter a password *somewhere* when the drive is connected? How is this password obtained when you boot with the drive attached? Also, at what point in the boot sequence does the pi stop or fail? What message is on your screen at the time

Comment: @M.Rostami - I think that setting is applicable when **booting** from USB - which is not what is happening here

Comment: @M.Rostami I don't know if there's a log. The machine is running headless.

Comment: @jaromandaX The USB dive ask for a password when I attach it after system boot.

Comment: yes Ryan, I know ... how is it supposed to get a password if you boot it with the drive attached?

Comment: I still don't get this. So now the problem is, the password is not stored and that's why it's unable to boot? The Pi's system itself is not encrypted, only the attached drive.

Comment: Are you sure the power supply is not guilty?

Comment: @M.Rostami How can I check that?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/91433/44221