# Raspberry Pi undervoltage strange issues

Tags: pi-2, hardware

So I have an old Rpi2 B, and I was getting an undervoltage error trying to run OctoPrint on an old bundled PSU.

I swapped for a 5V/4A PSU with the same error, I only have the power supply and an Ethernet cable connected. Could my Pi be broken in some way?

I took it a step further and ran 5.15V on the GPIO pins from a decent lab PSU. (I know it's risky, but it's a last resort.)
This drew around 400 mA and still had the same error. I then tested the voltage out of the USB sockets and found around 4.8 v.

My theory was that plugging in my 3D printer would pull enough current to under-volt the PI; however, even without the printer connected, the issue still occurs, so even that theory is out the window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Answer (score 1):

The latest [*official* documentation on power requirements](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply) for all models of RPi shows:

| Product | PSU current rating | Max USB current draw | Typ bare-board current used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RPi 2 Model B | 1.8A | 1.2A | 350mA |

If your measurements are accurate, and you're not overclocking, your RPi is drawing a bit more current than specified, but not by a large amount. The other thing that can cause voltage drops is long power leads, or small wire gauge. Adjust this if possible with the shortest cable & largest AWG leads you can find.

You should also [check your board revision](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/UsefulShellTricks.md#tell-me-about-my-system) (it seems there was at least one revision), and review [the schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/model-b-revision-2-0-schematics/). Referring to the [2B schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.com/app/uploads/2012/10/Raspberry-Pi-R2.0-Schematics-Issue2.2_027.pdf), there is no voltage regulator, only a fusible link (F3; a.k.a. *polyfuse*): the `5V0` bus comes straight from the USB input. You should measure `5V0` between `TP1` and `TP2` & compare it against the reading on your external PS. If you have an oscilloscope, you could also take a look at `5V0` just to make sure it's quiet & stable.

If you make these measurements carefully, you may get useful information to further your troubleshooting. In other words, consider the elements in ***series*** with the supply: connectors, wire, fusible link, and note the voltage drops at each point.

You can also monitor `GPIO35` in software on the RPi 2B for state transitions (high to low), and/or use the `vcgencmd` command to gain some insights on how your system is performing. [There are a couple of good answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60593/how-raspbian-detects-under-voltage) that provide the "how-to" details to accomplish these tests.

The fact that the 2B has no voltage regulator between `VIN` and `5V0` *suggests* to me that your problem may be in the wiring or connectors, but there are numerous reports online re. issues with the polyfuse (F3 on the schematic) - [for example](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=67252).

Other than that, I'm not aware of any specific under-voltage issues with the 2B. If you find no issues with the steps described above, my advice would be to:

1. keep power leads short,
2. use heaviest AWG you can find, and
3. *drive on*